# domain-name dhcp option not applying to hostname -f

Tags: 12.04, networking, dns, dhcp

My Ubuntu 12.04.3 machine is not getting the domain-name option from dhcp applied to the FQDN returned by `hostname -f` (`dnsdomainname` returns nothing).

Ip config:

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:4d:d4:31:89:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.101.100.166/16 brd 10.101.255.255 scope global eth0
5: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.185.1/24 brd 192.168.185.255 scope global vmnet1
6: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.10.1/24 brd 172.16.10.255 scope global vmnet8
```

tail of dhcp lease:

```
# tail -16 /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases 
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 10.101.100.166;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
  option routers 10.101.0.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 14400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 10.101.200.1,10.101.200.2;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 10.101.200.1;
  option dhcp-renewal-time 7200;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 12600;
  option domain-name "eng.sophos";
  renew 4 2013/10/03 14:14:24;
  rebind 4 2013/10/03 16:01:08;
  expire 4 2013/10/03 16:31:08;
}
```

resolv.conf:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.101.200.1
nameserver 10.101.200.2
search eng.sophos
search eng.sophos green.sophos
```

/etc/hosts:

```
# head /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       abelard
```

Answer (score 2):

As specified in [RFC2132](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2132.txt), section 3.17, the DHCP `domain-name` option does not specify the domain name to be assigned to the client. It specifies the domain name that the client should use when resolving hostnames in DNS.

As your `/etc/resolv.conf` shows, `resolvconf` accordingly translates the option to a `search` keyword.

Apart from acting as the default naming context for unqualified hostnames (which can more generically be achieved using the `search` keyword in `resolv.conf`), there is no justification for setting the FQDN on a system, as this is a property of the naming system rather than the machine itself.